# Is there a fluentd plugin to send logs to two different servers?

Tags: fluentd

I want to send logs to two different loki server from fluentd.

```
        |-------> server1(matching condition1)  
fluentd |  
        |-------> server2(matching condition2)
```

Not sure about using copy plugin as the plugin is sending same data to different servers.
Following is the current configuration

```
    <filter kube.**>
      @type record_transformer
      enable_ruby true
      <record>
        label ${record["kubernetes"]["namespace_name"]}.${record["kubernetes"]["container_name"]}
        stack "#{ENV['STACK_NAME']}"
        environment "#{ENV['STACK_ENVIRONMENT']}"
        namespace ${record["kubernetes"]["namespace_name"]}
        container_name ${record["kubernetes"]["container_name"]}
        pod_id ${record["kubernetes"]["pod_id"]}
      </record>
    </filter>
    <match kube.**_intg_**.log kube.**_master_**.log>
      @type loki
      url "#{ENV['OUTPUT_HOST_1']}"
      username ""
      password ""
      label_keys "stack,environment,namespace,container_name,pod_id"
      remove_keys "label"
      flush_interval 10s
      flush_at_shutdown true
      buffer_chunk_limit 1m
    </match>
    <match kube.**_kube-system_**.log>
      @type loki
      url "#{ENV['OUTPUT_HOST_2']}"
      username ""
      password ""
      label_keys "stack,environment,namespace,container_name,pod_id"
      remove_keys "label"
      flush_interval 10s
      flush_at_shutdown true
      buffer_chunk_limit 1m
    </match>
   </filter>
```

Comment: Check [rewrite_tag_filter](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/rewrite_tag_filter) plugin.

Comment: what is the issue with the current configs?